# condition statements in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe that has the following columns:

- Date1
- Date2
- Duration (in days)

Where `Date2 = Date1+duration`.

I want to add a third date (date3) where `date3 = date2+x,`

where:

```
 Date3 = date2+15 if duration <30days   
 Date3 = date2+20 if  durations is from >=30days to  <=180days  
 Date3 = date2+30 if duration >180days.
```

My code is:

```
conditions =[
    (df['duration'] <30),
    (df['duration'] >= 30) & df['duration'] <=180),
    (df['duration'] >180)]
choices = [15,20,30]
df['date3'] = np.select(conditions,df['date2']+pd.to_timedelta(np.select(conditions, choices, default='null'),unit='d'))
```

If date2 = 2019-09-21, and duration is <30,

then date3 is outputted as 2019-09-21 00:00:00.00000015

so it’s considering the 15 as nanoseconds and not as days.

Any thoughts on how to make it understand that the 15 is days not nanoseconds?

I have the correct syntax for the to_timedelta statement, but not sure why its taking the delta as nanoseconds and not days.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

-Big_ears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...so I solved it...
In the choices, instead of

choices[15,20,30]

I had to write:

choices[pd.to_timedelta(15,units='days'),pd.to_timedelta(20,units='days'),pd.to_timedelta(30,units='days')]

-big_ears

Answer (score 0):

Did try your answer and wasnt successful. Maybe missed out something. This could work as well. Please Try;
**Generate Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({


 'Date2': ['2019-01-20', '2019-01-20', '2019-01-20', '2019-01-20'],
    'duration': [30, 90, 270, 15],
    'Date3': ['', '', '', '']
})
df
df['Date2']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date2'])
df['Date3']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date3'])
```

**Conditions**

```
 b=df['duration'].between(30,180)
 a=df['duration']<30
 c=df['duration']>180
```

**Apply conditions and Compute Data3**

```
df['Date3'] = np.where(a, df['Date2'] + pd.to_timedelta(15, unit='d'),df['Date3'])
df['Date3'] = np.where(b, df['Date2'] + pd.to_timedelta(20, unit='d'),df['Date3'])
df['Date3'] = np.where(c, df['Date2'] + pd.to_timedelta(30, unit='d'),df['Date3'])

df
```

Comment: in the condition statement, I did not use the between fcn.  I used =>30 and <180.